# Highlight one specific bar in plotly bar chart [python]

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm using a plotly.express bar chart to visualize categorical data like this:

```
fig = px.bar(data, x='Algorithm', y='NDE', text_auto='.3f', color='Algorithm', 
color_discrete_map={'Ensembling':'orange', 'CO':'blue', 'Mean':'blue', 'DAE':'blue', 
                              'S2P':'blue', 'S2S':'blue', 'WinGru':'blue'})
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', xaxis={'categoryorder':'total descending'})
fig.show()
```

Gives me this result:
[image]

However, that way of highlighting a specific bar in the chart seems somewhat "overengineered" to me.

So my question is: Does anyone know a more simple way to highlight one specific bar in a python plotly express bar chart?

Thanks for any suggestions! :-)

Comment: It can also be accomplished by rewriting the internal information of the graph; insert it in the line before `fig.show()`. `fig.data[3]['marker']['color'] = 'orange'`

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Referenced by fig.data is a tuple containing one single Bar() object. This object has a reference named 'marker' but to me it looks like it sets the color for all markers that are displayed:
`(Bar({
     'alignmentgroup': 'True',
     'hovertemplate': 'Algorithm=%{x}<br>NDE=%{y}<extra></extra>',
     'legendgroup': '',
     'marker': {'color': '#636efa', 'pattern': {'shape': ''}},
     'name': '',
     ...
     'x': array(['..., dtype=object),
     'xaxis': 'x',
     'y': array(...]),
     'yaxis': 'y'
 }),)`

Comment: `fig.data[3]` points to the fourth bar graph. Its color is specified.

Comment: fig.data[3] points to nowhere and raises an IndexError when called, because fig.data references a tuple with only one object in it.

Comment: We have confirmed this with the data you responded to, so please try it. Please select the most populous country for the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to be that explicit with `color_discrete_map`. You can define a default color and then overwrite. This still generates the same kind of `color_discrete_map` dictionary as in your example, but it's more robust.

```
import plotly.express as px

default_color = "blue"
colors = {"China": "red"}

data = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 1952")

color_discrete_map = {
    c: colors.get(c, default_color) 
    for c in data.country.unique()}

fig = px.bar(data, x='country', y='pop', color='country',
             color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)
fig.update_traces(showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: do you know a way of getting rid of the legend on the side though? cause (at least for me) it doesn't feel very appealing to have a very long legend for the same color and values as on the xaxis on the side